# Can I install SQL Server and IIS on Windows 8.1 professional Edition

Tags: sql-server, windows, iis, windows-8.1, windows-server

Can I install SQL Server and IIS on Windows 8.1 professional Edition, and run it as a web server?

-- edited --

How about Microsoft Server Essentials 2012 R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But there are connection limitations with IIS on workstation editions of Windows:

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2012/11/13/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit.aspx